# how to display the telugu,hindi and other pdf files in phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

I am very new to develop pdf file implementations in phonegap mobile apps ,my problem is "how to display the telugu,hindi and other  pdf files  in phonegap app?. please help me & waiting for ue response.

Thanks 
venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the available plugin viewers. You can find the best known in http://plugreg.com/search?q=Pdf

Answer (score 0):

Hey and welcome to cordova,
maybe you try it with the [Cordova File-Opener Plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2). This Plugin is able to upen up PDFs, Word-Files etc. I don't know how exactly the Hindi language is supported, but maybe you give it a try.

After you installed the Plugin via your terminal you can use this code to upen a PDF:

```
<script>
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        '/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf', 
        'application/pdf', 
        { 
            error : function(errorObj) { 
                alert('Error status: ' + errorObj.status + ' - Error message: ' + errorObj.message); 
            },
            success : function () {
                alert('file opened successfully');              
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Tell me why you downvoted my answer and maybe i'll edit it the right way. But only downvote and not telling anything is not the right way.